# Home Folder Files Intermittently missing for user

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, file-server, home-directory

We are having a weird issue that has been ongoing for months where one of our users will have files missing from her Home Folder mapped as H from active directory not show up. The files that don't show up typically change usually when she reboots and she'll be able to see the files she could not see prior, but different files will be missing. The H drive is saved on our file server. We have a Windows Server 2008 R2 AD, File Server, and Windows 7 client the user is on. I have double checked the permissions on all of the files and she have access to all of them. In rough order over the last few months I have tried the following

- New network drop to different switch
- Switch Computer
- Delete user profile on computer, active directory, and home folder on file server and recreate all of them

This is only occuring with the one user and the files that it happens to are different every time. Anyone have any ideas of things I could try?

Edit: I forgot to mention if you RDP into the fileserver itself everything is always there and fine.

Comment: Did you see if they are using sync tool or other replication where the stuff is being synced to an empty directory?

Comment: I'm not familiar with sync tool, but the account was created in house and the folder auto created through the account on the profile tab of AD for the user when the path was typed in.

Comment: If the user can install apps on their own PC I'd start there. This sounds like a backup tool or something similar.

Comment: @JeremyMcDevitt You're able to recreate this issue on DIFFERENT computers but with the same user account, correct? Based on your itemized listed, that's what I'm getting from that.  Do you allow your users to be local admins on the Windows 7 machines or would this one user be one on all the PCs you signed onto with this account to confirm that's the issue. If it is software related, then I assume it's going to be software on all machines that has something tied to this one account, live an AV software package with policies or something along those lines (e.g. Kaspersky, CA, Norton, etc.).

Comment: Correct, but she does use a piece of scanning software called paper port which I'm wondering if that's doing something. She's out today, but I'm going to see if removing that does anything. Thank you for the help and I'll follow up.